# What is the correct way to implement a "Constant object"?

Tags: .net, vb.net, oop

I am trying something that strikes me as very common, but I am struggling with the *good* way to implement it.

I have created a 'Tag' class, as follows:

```
Public Class Tag
    Public Name As String
    Private Server As Server
    ...
End Class
```

Tags are created during runtime, so it makes sense to me.
However, those tags are stored on servers, defined like this:

```
Public Class Server
    Public Name As String
    Public Location As Location (<- An Enum)
    ...
End Class
```

The servers are known before run-time, and never change, never move, and so on.

Right now, I create them at the very beginning of the program, like any object, and store them in variables:

```
Dim Server1 As New Server
Server1.Name = "Server1"
Server1.Location = "Somewhere"

Dim Server2 As New Server
....
```

I feel that it's not the way you should do this, but I have not a clue about what is the correct way.

To sum up, I have 'constant objects', meaning objects whose properties are known during coding, and never change at runtime. What is the best way to make those objects accessible to other objects at runtime?

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

These *constant objects* are usually called *immutable objects*.

In .NET, the easiest path to get *immutable objects* is to design classes with a constructor and read-only properties.

```
' An immutable object
Public Class Server
    Public Sub New(name As String)
        Name = name 
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property Name() As String
End Class
```